# Mysql query distinct + multiple

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to do this query:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM user k
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT id, tagName, b.guid, name, owner, publicKey
         FROM noteTags a
         INNER JOIN (
            SELECT * 
            FROM note
            ORDER BY guid
            LIMIT 0 , 12
         )b ON a.guid = b.guid ORDER BY b.id DESC
   )l ON k.owner = l.owner
```

But I want it to return DISTINCT b.guids.

Structure of the tables:

```
note
|
|=id
|=name
|=guid
|=owner
|=publicKey

noteTags
|
|=guid
|=tagName

user
|
|=owner
|=username
|=auth
```

Basically I want to select ALL data (with the limit on the deeper inner join) and return DISTINCT guids

Thanks!

Comment: this is an example, if there are two records with the same GUI, which of the following will be shown `GUI=1, Colname=1` or `GUI=1, Colname=2` ?

Comment: doesn't matter, both has equal values

Comment: so you mean any of the following as long as only 1 GUI is shown.

Comment: one more thing why do you need to limit it `LIMIT 0 , 12`?

Comment: which of the following tables: `note`, `notetag` that contains multiple but the same `GUI`?

Comment: noteTag contains multiple GUI.

Comment: LIMIT is for separation purpose

Comment: I have to go, I'll be back soon

Answer (score 0):

Here's my initial answer,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    note a
        INNER JOIN user b
            ON a.owner = b.owner
        INNER JOIN notetags c
            ON a.guid = b.guid
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT guid, MAX(tagName) maxTag
            FROM notetags
            GROUP BY guid
        ) d ON c.guid = d.guid AND
                c.tagName = d.maxTag
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

SELECT * 
   FROM user k 
   INNER JOIN ( 
      SELECT id, tagName, b.guid, name, owner, publicKey 
         FROM noteTags a 
         INNER JOIN ( 
            select id, name, MIN(guid) as guid, owner, publicKey 
            FROM note 
            GROUP BY guid 
            LIMIT 0 , 12 
         )b ON a.guid = b.guid ORDER BY b.id DESC  
   )l ON k.owner = l.owner